# Why doesn't this Java servlet url-pattern/RequestMapping work?

Tags: java, servlets

I have this RequestMapping/method defined:

```
@RequestMapping( value={"/ViewReport/json", "/ViewReport/*/json"} , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView TestJson(final Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("Hello", "Goodbye");
    json.put("request", request.getRequestURL());
    model.addAttribute("fnord", json.toJSONString());   
    return new ModelAndView("reportViewJson");  
}
```

In my `web.xml` file I have the following:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>autoreport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewReport/*/json</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>autoreport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewReport/json</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, when I navigate to `/ViewReport/json` I get back the expected JSON. However, when I navigate to `/ViewReport/42/json` I get a 404.

I've got the following logs from when my server starts up:

```
[ INFO] 23:51(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/] onto handler 'reportViewController'

[DEBUG] 23:51(AbstractBeanFactory.java:doGetBean:246)
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reportViewController'

[ INFO] 23:51(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/json] onto handler 'reportViewController'

[DEBUG] 23:51(AbstractBeanFactory.java:doGetBean:246)
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reportViewController'

[ INFO] 23:51(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/json.*] onto handler 'reportViewController'

[DEBUG] 23:51(AbstractBeanFactory.java:doGetBean:246)
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reportViewController'

[ INFO] 23:51(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/json/] onto handler 'reportViewController'

[DEBUG] 23:51(AbstractBeanFactory.java:doGetBean:246)
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reportViewController'

[ INFO] 23:51(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/*/json] onto handler 'reportViewController'

[DEBUG] 23:51(AbstractBeanFactory.java:doGetBean:246)
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reportViewController'

[ INFO] 23:51(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/*/json.*] onto handler 'reportViewController'

[DEBUG] 23:51(AbstractBeanFactory.java:doGetBean:246)
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'reportViewController'

[ INFO] 23:51(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:registerHandler:315)
Mapped URL path [/ViewReport/*/json/] onto handler 'reportViewController'
```

### Update 2

In my `autoreport-servlet.xml` I've got this:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property
        name="webBindingInitializer">
        <!-- Configures Spring MVC DataBinder instances -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What is that `autoreport` servlet you are mapping? the `DispatcherServlet`? If so, try mapping it to `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following mapping is invalid due to [Servlet Specification (Section 11)](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>autoreport</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ViewReport/*/json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

A `*`is not allowed in between a path mapping. For path mappings it is only allowed at the end with a `/*`. (Well, when nitpicking it is in fact valid and allowed but it isn't treated as a wildcard as intended.)

Cited from the Servlet Specifiaction:

> In theWeb application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

So your pattern `/ViewReport/*/json` is an exact match pattern with no wildcard.
That's the reason why `/ViewReport/42/json` gives a `HTTP 404`, because it does not match any pattern.

Comment: so how do I get a mapping there? According to [this document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates) it's possible - "a method can have any number of `@PathVariable` annotations" - right?

Comment: Yes, that's the Spring annotation supporting it. But it is not supported for servlet mapping in web.xml. Spring has a dispatcher servlet that must be mapped in web.xml according to the Servlet Specifiaction. But the Dispatcher Servlet can evaluate the paths from Spring's annotation (within the scope it is defined in web.xml).

Comment: Okay - so how do I get the Spring annotation to work? Because right now it's not - not when I have a `@PathVariable` anyway

Answer (score 0):

Because when using spring MVC you don't configure the mapping in the `web.xml` for each controller method, that's what the `@RequestMapping` annotation is for.

You configure the spring dispatcher servlet once for all to a URL, then the `@RequestMapping` annotations handle the mapping, relatively to the spring dispatcher servlet URL.

For example is spring dispatcher servlet is mapped to `/mvc/*`, and you declare a method with `@RequestMapping("/xyz")`, the URL for this method will be `<contextPath>/mvc/xyz`. If you configured spring dispatcher servlet to `/*` the URL will be `<contextPath>/xyz`.

Comment: So what does that mean in this context?

Comment: It means you need to remove from the web.xml the URL mapping you showed , then if you want to access your method with the URL '/ViewReport/json', you need to configure spring servlet to the pattern "/*".

Comment: It appears that doesn't actually work - I just removed the `servlet-mapping` sections and now just have one with `/*`, and I can't access `/ViewReport/json`. Getting access to that one has never been the problem, though. It's been the getting access to the `/ViewReport/{id}/json`.